# How to match struct fields in Rust?

Tags: rust

Can Rust match struct fields? For example, this code:

```
struct Point {
    x: bool,
    y: bool,
}

let point = Point { x: false, y: true };

match point {
    point.x => println!("x is true"),
    point.y => println!("y is true"),
}
```

Should result in:

```
y is true
```

Comment: How do you propose this to work with... non-boolean fields? For example, how would this work with a `struct Person { surname: String, age: u8 }`?

Answer (score 75):

> Can Rust match struct fields?

It is described in the Rust book in the ["Destructuring structs"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#destructuring-to-break-apart-values) chapter.

```
match point {
    Point { x: true, .. } => println!("x is true"),
    Point { y: true, .. } => println!("y is true"),
    _ => println!("something else"),
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The syntax presented in your question doesn't make any sense; it seems that you just want to use a normal `if` statement:

```
if point.x { println!("x is true") }
if point.y { println!("y is true") }
```

---

I'd highly recommend re-reading [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/), specifically the chapters on

- [enums](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html)
- [`match`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch06-02-match.html)
- [patterns](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch18-00-patterns.html)

Once you've read that, it should become clear that `point.x` isn't a pattern, so it cannot be used on the left side of a match arm.

Comment: Most functional programming languages have such features, it's actually extremely useful to avoid having nested if/else as regular low-level languages that do not have pattern-matching would require... so, I recommend you to read about pattern-matching :D

Comment: @MarceloBoeira I’m quite familiar with Rust’s pattern matching. You’ll note that I’ve linked to two specific pieces of documentation covering them. The OPs request isn’t about pattern matching as expressed in Rust. They haven’t even expressed what should happen when both fields are true.