# Why do I get an error when pattern matching a struct-like enum variant with fields?

Tags: enums, rust, pattern-matching

I can't get rid of an error on this code:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Copy, Clone)]
pub enum OperationMode {
    ECB,
    CBC { iv: [u8; 16] },
}

pub struct AES {
    key: Vec<u8>,
    nr: u8,
    mode: OperationMode,
}

impl AES {
    pub fn decrypt(&mut self, input: &Vec<u8>) {
        match self.mode {
            OperationMode::ECB => {},
            OperationMode::CBC(_) => {},
        };
    }
}
```

The pattern matching at the end of the `decrypt` function gives an error:

```
error[E0532]: expected tuple struct/variant, found struct variant `OperationMode::CBC`
  --> src/main.rs:17:13
   |
17 |             OperationMode::CBC(_) => {},
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ did you mean `OperationMode::CBC { /* fields */ }`?
```

It tells me to look at the output of `rustc --explain E0532` for help, which I did.

They show this example of wrong code:

> ```
> enum State {
>     Succeeded,
>     Failed(String),
> }
>
> fn print_on_failure(state: &State) {
>     match *state {
>         // error: expected unit struct/variant or constant, found tuple
>         //        variant `State::Failed`
>         State::Failed => println!("Failed"),
>         _ => ()
>     }
> }
> ```

In this example, the error occurs because `State::Failed` has a field which isn't matched. It should be `State::Failed(ref msg)`.

In my case I'm matching the field of my enum because I'm doing  `OperationMode::CBC(_)`. Why does the error happen?

Comment: [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec) or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423).

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Enum variants have three possible syntaxes:

- unit

  ```
  enum A { One }
  ```
- tuple

  ```
  enum B { Two(u8, bool) }
  ```
- struct

  ```
  enum C { Three { a: f64, b: String } }
  ```

You have to use the same syntax when pattern matching as the syntax the variant was defined as:

- unit

  ```
  match something {
      A::One => { /* Do something */ }
  }
  ```
- tuple

  ```
  match something {
      B::Two(x, y) => { /* Do something */ }
  }
  ```
- struct

  ```
  match something {
      C::Three { a: another_name, b } => { /* Do something */ }
  }
  ```

Beyond that, you can use various patterns that allow ignoring a value, such as `_` or `..`. In this case, you need curly braces and the `..` catch-all:

```
OperationMode::CBC { .. } => { /* Do something */ }
```

See also:

- [Ignoring Values in a Pattern in *The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#ignoring-values-in-a-pattern)
- [Appendix B: Operators and Symbols in *The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/appendix-02-operators.html)
- [How to match struct fields in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41390457/how-to-match-struct-fields-in-rust)

Comment: _Technically_, parenthesized structs and variants may also be be compared using braces, with integers as field names (`B::Two { 0: x, 1: y }`). This is definitely not something I would expect to see in normal code, but can be useful in macros.