# How do I assert an enum is a specific variant if I don't care about its fields?

Tags: rust

I'd like to check enums with fields in tests while ignoring the actual value of the fields for now.

Consider the following example:

```
enum MyEnum {
    WithoutFields,
    WithFields { field: String },
}

fn return_with_fields() -> MyEnum {
    MyEnum::WithFields {
        field: "some string".into(),
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn example() {
        assert_eq!(return_with_fields(), MyEnum::WithFields {..});
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e9e9726c146ecb20ea837f15e77e9410&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

I'd like to use `assert_eq!` here, but the compiler tells me:

```
error: expected expression, found `}`
  --> src/lib.rs:18:64
   |
18 |         assert_eq!(return_with_fields(), MyEnum::WithFields {..});
   |                                                                ^ expected expression
```

This is similar to [Why do I get an error when pattern matching a struct-like enum variant with fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50775023/why-do-i-get-an-error-when-pattern-matching-a-struct-like-enum-variant-with-fiel), but the solution does not apply in my case.

Of course, I can use `match` and do it myself, but being able to use `assert_eq!` would be less work.

Comment: What `MyEnum::WithFields {..}` is suppose to do ? https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=dfa1b92d4a88f83273cb0bb95f226612&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015

Comment: Hi :) I think your question is answered by ["Compare enums only by variant, not value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32554285/compare-enums-only-by-variant-not-value). In short: use [`mem::discriminant`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.discriminant.html). If you don't think this link answers your question, please explain why your question is different.

Comment: @Stargateur it is supposed to ignore the fields value and just match on ``WithFields``.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt Sadly that does not work, the rust compiler still wants me to specify the field somehow.

Comment: @PhilippLudwig You can't compare a variant with something that doesn't exist, do you want something like that ? https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e7df26067b37cbeea7624a181645dd3a&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015

Comment: @Stargateur yeah, I'd like something like that. Seems a bit much though.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

## Rust 1.42

You can use [`std::matches`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.matches.html):

```
assert!(matches!(return_with_fields(), MyEnum::WithFields { .. }));
```

## Previous versions

Your original code can be made to work with a new macro:

```
macro_rules! is_enum_variant {
    ($v:expr, $p:pat) => (
        if let $p = $v { true } else { false }
    );
}

#[test]
fn example() {
    assert!(is_enum_variant!(return_with_fields(), MyEnum::WithoutFields {..}));
}
```

Personally, I tend to add methods to my enums:

```
fn is_with_fields(&self) -> bool {
    match self {
        MyEnum::WithFields { .. } => true,
        _ => false,
    }
}
```

I also tend to avoid struct-like enums and instead put in extra work:

```
enum MyEnum {
    WithoutFields,
    WithFields(WithFields),
}

struct WithFields { field: String }

impl MyEnum {
    fn is_with_fields(&self) -> bool {
        match self {
            MyEnum::WithFields(_) => true,
            _ => false,
        }
    }

    fn as_with_fields(&self) -> Option<&WithFields> {
        match self {
            MyEnum::WithFields(x) => Some(x),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
    
    fn into_with_fields(self) -> Option<WithFields> {
        match self {
            MyEnum::WithFields(x) => Some(x),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that some day, enum variants can be made into their own type to avoid this extra struct.

Comment: A gotcha I ran into with `assert!(matches!(...))` is that, unlike `assert_eq!`, the argument order matters, and you must use a literal for the second argument. `assert!(matches!(exp_result, act_result))` will never panic, because `exp_result` can always be matched with the "name" `act_result`. You need to destructure at least one level in order to trigger an actual match, like the presented `assert!(matches!(exp_result, MyEnum::WithFields { .. }))`. Somewhat obvious in hindsight, but maybe this comment will help someone save a few minutes of debugging.

Comment: @SeanKelleher You'd also get a warning from the compiler: `warning: unused variable: \`act_result\``

Answer (score 8):

**If you are using Rust 1.42 and later, see [Shepmaster's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51123901/393701).**

A simple solution here would be to do the opposite assertion:

```
assert!(return_with_fields() != MyEnum::WithoutFields);
```

or even more simply:

```
assert_ne!(return_with_fields(), MyEnum::WithoutFields);
```

Of course if you have more members in your enum, you'll have to add more asserts to cover all possible cases.

Alternatively, and this what OP probably had in mind, since `assert!` just panics in case of failure, the test can use pattern matching and call `panic!` directly in case something is wrong:

```
match return_with_fields() {
    MyEnum::WithFields {..} => {},
    MyEnum::WithoutFields => panic!("expected WithFields, got WithoutFields"),
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a good idea. I'm still wondering though if there is a more straight-forward solution. Or maybe I will just have to create my own macro.

Comment: @SirDarius Thanks for providing the source, this is interesting. I will accept your answer, maybe you want to include these additional information there.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a macro like @Shepmaster proposed, but with more error reporting (like the existing `assert!` and `assert_eq!` macros:

```rust
macro_rules! assert_variant {
    ($value:expr, $pattern:pat) => ({
        let value = &$value;

        if let $pattern = value {} else {
            panic!(r#"assertion failed (value doesn't match pattern):
   value: `{:?}`,
 pattern: `{}`"#, value, stringify!($pattern))
        }
    })

    // TODO: Additional patterns for trailing args, like assert and assert_eq
}
```

[Rust playground demonstrating this example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f349d1b9dafa29e8e07048a1915e3018)