# Match on field inside enum data in Rust?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

Let's say I have the enum:

```rust
enum Foo {
    Bar {baz: Option<Buzz> },
}


struct Buzz {}
```

is there a way to match on whether `baz` is `None` or not?

[How to match struct fields in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41390457/how-to-match-struct-fields-in-rust) doesn't seem to work because Rust interprets

```rust
match foo {
    Foo::Bar { baz: Buzz } => {
    },
    Foo::Bar { baz: None } => {
    }
}
```

the `baz: Bar` as a rename.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to match struct fields in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41390457/how-to-match-struct-fields-in-rust)

Comment: Oh, the solution there doesn't seem to work. I'll add an edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The opposite of `None` is `Some`:

```
let foo = Foo::Bar{ baz: None };
match foo {
    Foo::Bar{ baz: Some(_) } => println!("Bar with some"),
    Foo::Bar{ baz: None } => println!("Bar with none"),
}
```